# Second order D.E. - general solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If $y=y(x)$, and we have the differential equation

$y''=-k^2y$

for some constant $k>0$, then wolfram alpha gives the general solution as $y=A\cos(kx)+B\sin(kx)$. I've also seen this result used in various other situations. My first question is, aren't the functions

$y=A\cos(kx+x_1)+B\sin(kx+x_2)$ for some constant angles $x_1,x_2$

more general? They clearly satisfy the differential equation. I know this isn't a massive problem but it's irritating me. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is essentially the same, if you expand the formula for the cosine or sine of a sum. Then $A,B$ would be different, but since without initial values conditions they are arbitrary, then you encompass all solutions anyway.

Comment: Oh I see, alright thanks a lot!